# Kivy: Resizing the window moves the window

Tags: python, kivy

I am running a minimal Kivy-based program. When I run the application, the window appears as expected. When I try to resize the image, by clicking and dragging the window's bottom right corner towards the bottom right with my mouse, the window's top corner moves in the opposite direction (top left) and the window doesn't resize as expected.

Dragging in other directions or on other corners results in various erratic results that both modify the position and size of the window.

- Dragging either bottom corner makes the window move up (if the window starts at the top left of the screen, the drag seems to behave normally)
- Dragging either top corner moves the window down (if the window starts at the bottom left of the screen, the drag seems to behave normally)
- In all cases the window seems to be moving to the left

Does anyone know why this is happening? Am I missing something?

- Using Python 3.6.9
- Ubuntu 18.04
- 2 monitor system (both are 1920x1080)

Code follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Moo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

UPDATE: I am seeing an error about pygame being deprecated, not sure if this is related. I'm not using pygame explicitly so I don't have much control over this.

[WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Pygame has been deprecated and will be removed after 1.11.0: Call to deprecated function **init** in /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py line 27.Called from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/image/**init**.py line 460 by load().

Answer (score 1):

To address the pygame warning, I used the recommendations from this post:
[Python Kivy won't use SDL2, insists on using pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908859/python-kivy-wont-use-sdl2-insists-on-using-pygame)

I guess I was missing some dependencies when I installed kivy the first time.
I uninstalled it using pip3, installed the missing dependencies and then reinstalled it and it appears to work correctly now.

However, now I'm concerned about distributing this application, as I am not sure eventual users will install kivy correctly as a requirement. I may try other modules.